# Как разрабатывать на React Native используя VirtualBox с Ubuntu как среду разработки и Windows 10 c Android Studio как эмулятор Android

Tags: windows, ubuntu, react-native, virtualbox, android-emulator

Есть **VirtualBox** с **Ubuntu Server**.
Хотелось бы там создать **среду разработки ReactNative** (установить `nodejs`, `npm`, `java` и т.д) и там-же запускать сборку и запуск на эмуляторе `npx reat-native start`, `npx react-native run-android`. Но сам эмулятор иметь на основной системе **Windows 10**.

Нужно ли для установки эмулятора использовать **Android Studio**, или можно использовать какой-либо другой эмулятор? И как реализовать такую связку, что-бы **React Native** и **запуск/сборка** приложения были на **VirtualBox**, а **эмулятор Android** был на **Windows** ?

Comment: А зачем андройд студию запускать на винде, если она нормально идёт на убунте?

Comment: @donRumata, там ведь Ubuntu Server без графической оболочки

Comment: Так, ок, а какой вообще смысл разделения?